# Using COM port 8086 Assembly

Tags: assembly, serial-port, x86-16

I am trying to send data over the COM port using assembly language. I am using DOSBOX on windows to allow running 16 bit applications. I am also using MASM 5.1. Windows shows me that my first COM port is at 03F8H. I used INT 14H with 0 assigned to DX nothing was sent, Tried assigning 03F8H to the DX but it was no good.

```
MOV DX,0H
MOV AL,'1'
MOV AH,01H
INT 14H
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
```

After setting DOSBOX's serial port to the direct one it just set all the lines to 0

Comment: Can you show your code? You mentioned port `03F8H` but you'd use that for an `out` instruction. If you are using `int 14h` you don't use the port addresses. It wants a port number (0, 1, 2, or 3). Also, how are you checking that it works? the serial modes need to be set properly (baud rate, etc) and whatever is receiving match.

Comment: What version of Windows ?

Comment: Are you the correct [configuration](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Configuration:SerialPort)?

Comment: windows 7
MOV DX,0H
MOV AL,'1'
MOV AH,01H
INT 14H

Comment: i'll try assigning the dosbox serial port to the real com and check if it's going to work

Comment: If you have code samples, please add them formatted to your problem statement. It's hard to read code in SO comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting DOSBOX's Serial port it worked. Thanks a lot guys